# Easy examples for multiprocessing in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3, parallel-processing

I've gone through a large number of forum threads and cannot make sense of how possible it is to easily run two tools at the same time in PyQGIS.

Basically what I'm wanting to do is:

```py
def function1():
    processing.run("gdalsomething"...)
def function2():
    processing.run("gdalsomethingelse"...)

doAtTheSameTime( function1() , function2() )
```

I've tried the Python threading module (but learnt I was wanting multiprocessing, not multithreading?)

I've tried the multiprocessing module but that spits out an array of errors (including `sys.argv` not existing), perhaps relating to the fact that `__name__` refuses to be `__main__`, and is `__console__` instead  (not that I know what that means)

Does anyone have a very simple example of running two QGIS tools at the same time in PyQGIS? (If it is even possible?)

Comment: Have you tried using subtasks? https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html

Comment: Yes I have, though I get an assertion error like in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419922/pyqgis-task-manager-not-working

Comment: Also, I think it may be possible to run two QGIS tools at the same time by setting up multiple python scripts to run QGIS tools without QGIS being open (i.e passing a python script into "...\bin\qgis-ltr.bat"), though I was hoping to avoid having to do this...

Comment: The linked question probably used GUI classes. Do you do that too? If you post a minimal reproducible example as a new question one could try to fix the crashes.

Comment: I was worried about splitting things apart too much with a new question. I think maybe this is all related. Looking at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40472 made me think maybe this isn't currently possible unless you have two instances of QGIS open?

Comment: @Taras instead of completely removing the user's solution from their question (yes, wrong place) without any respectful comment or notice, why not suggest to them to post it as answer? You just erase someone's hard work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you follow [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | 15. Tasks - doing heavy work in the background](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html#task-from-a-processing-algorithm) to create your tasks but below is the explanation of your error.

---

In Python functions are objects that you can pass around by name.

[`QgsTask.fromFunction`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/latest/core/QgsTask.html#qgis.core.QgsTask.fromFunction) requires you to pass a function object to it.

Your code currently passes the return values of your functions instead because you execute the functions (the `()`s). In Python, functions return `None` if there is no explicit return statement with a different value.

So instead of getting a function object, `QgsTask.fromFunction` gets `None` and the assertion fails.

Try:

```py
import random
from qgis.core import *

def one():
    processing.run("native:slope", {'INPUT':'...Dem.tif','Z_FACTOR':1,'OUTPUT':'...Slope1.tif'})
def two():
    processing.run("native:slope", {'INPUT':'...Dem.tif','Z_FACTOR':2,'OUTPUT':'...Slope2.tif'})

task1 = QgsTask.fromFunction('Please work', one)  # <- changed
task2 = QgsTask.fromFunction('Please work 2', two)  # <- changed

task1.addSubTask(task2)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task1)
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense that without the brackets you're not calling the function but simply referring to it. After that I also realised with what was in the link you sent that the functions must have a parameter called "task". Updated code above. Now when I look at my CPU usage I can see that they're definitely running in parallel, thanks.

Comment: Awesome! The `task` is automatically passed to the function so that you can e.g. update the progress indicator from it or stop it if the user asked QGIS to interrupt the whole thing. To handle progression after a task has finished you can pass another function using the `on_finished` parameter. https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html#task-from-function

Answer (score 1):

I've made some more progression on this.

---

INITIAL CODE UPDATE following on from bugmenot's help:

The below code works, and as far as I can tell this is the simplest possible way to run two tools at the same time in PyQGIS

Critically, the functions which are used in the `QgsTask` definition must have  a parameter called `task`

```py
from qgis.core import *

def one(task):
    processing.run("native:slope", {'INPUT':'...Dem.tif','Z_FACTOR':1,'OUTPUT':'...Slope1.tif'})
def two(task):
    processing.run("native:slope", {'INPUT':'...Dem.tif','Z_FACTOR':2,'OUTPUT':'...Slope2.tif'})

task1 = QgsTask.fromFunction('ItWorks', one)
task2 = QgsTask.fromFunction('ItWorks2', two)

task1.addSubTask(task2)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task1)
```

Please note that the script does not wait for `addTask` to complete, and simply powers on, hence why more advanced setups have handling to figure out when the task has completed

---

I've also attempted to try and run several tools in sequence, though with a set up such that I want one task to not start until after two other tasks have completed

```py
def firstProcess(task):
    processing.run("qgis:rastercalculator", ...)
    time.sleep(0.1)

def secondProcess(task):
    processing.run("qgis:rastercalculator", ...)
    time.sleep(0.1)

firstProcessTask = QgsTask.fromFunction('FirstProcess', firstProcess)
secondProcessTask = QgsTask.fromFunction('SecondProcess', secondProcess)

firstProcessTask.addSubTask(secondProcessTask)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(firstProcessTask)

    
####################################


def thirdProcess(task):
    try:
        firstProcessTask.waitForFinished(timeout = 20000000)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("...")
    try:
        secondProcessTask.waitForFinished(timeout = 20000000)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("...")
    processing.run("qgis:rastercalculator", ...)   

thirdProcessTask = QgsTask.fromFunction('ThirdProcess', thirdProcess)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(thirdProcessTask)
```

It's a little clunky, but it's the best I've been able to do given that if two tasks are run together through `addSubTask` they appear to trigger `task.waitForFinished` independently

If anyone has any improvements that would be great